# React Native Animation skipping to end value

Tags: android, react-native, vue.js, mobile, vue-native

I'm using React Native Animations in my Vue Native app. They normally work fine, but for some reason when I try to animate paddingTop and paddingBottom, the values skip to their end value rather than animating smoothly through them.

This seems to only happen if there are a lot of views (15+) on the screen. Note, not all of these views are animating, just the one! Also note that animating the opacity of these views DOES work fine, just the padding animation is skipping.

I can't use `useNativeDriver` because paddingTop/Bottom aren't supported, and easing functions don't seem to help. If I crank the duration time, then the animations will be more normal on the ones skipping, but obviously extremely slow on the ones not.

Is this just a limitation of React Native/Vue Native?

A snippet (note opacityGrowth isn't being animated at the same time as paddingMod):

```
        <animated:view
            :style="{opacity: opacityGrowth,
                    paddingTop: paddingMod,
                    paddingBottom: paddingMod }">



        widenLetter () {
            var time = 300
            // Animate the letter as we read it, making it inflate
            Animated.timing(this.paddingMod, {
                toValue: 20,
                duration: time,
            }).start()
        },

        shrinkLetter () {
            var time = 300
            // Animate the letter after we read it, making it deflate
            Animated.timing(this.paddingMod, {
                toValue: 0,
                duration: time,
            }).start()
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

This was due to a property of the component changing in the middle of the animation. Note this property had NOTHING TO DO with the animation itself, but when the parent component changed a property it passed to the child component (which was doing the animation on itself), it caused the component to immediately refresh and force stop all animations